# How to install Opera 24 for Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, opera

I installed Opera Browser (Version 12.16) on my Ubuntu 12.04, but I couldn't find the **Turbo Mode** in it.

So I am planning to install Opera 24 Developer version.

Can Opera 24 Developer be installed on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/06/opera-linux-chromium-download-released

Comment: Great source Mateo. Unfortunately it does not offer a link to the download page.

Comment: True! I don't get OMG design :/

Comment: now there is a beta out, things are moving fast on this - http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/09/opera-25-beta-adds-linux-support-new-bookmarking-feature

Answer (score 1):

From the official site you can see the difference between stable version for Linux and other OS.

Latest stable version for Linux is 12.16:

[image: linux]

Latest stable version for Mac is 24.0:

[image: mac]

Thankfully, Opera has bring newer version into Linux in the Developer branch. You can get the latest version for Linux from the [Opera Developer page](http://www.opera.com/developer).

[image: new version]